# How do I see which queries are running slow

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual x86_64) and Percona's mysql server.

I know im getting slow queries, but im not sure where I find what they are so I can try to remedy them.

Is someone able to help me find where the logs are, and if i'll be able to tell what the offending queries are.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by enable mysql_long_queries, and then examine the log output.

in my.cnf under [mysqld]

```
long_query_time         = 1
log-slow-queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log
```

and go from there.

You can also use:

```
show processlist
show full processlist
```

to see which queries are currently running.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you're still having a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that our friend rfelsburg said is correct and you should do. However, I have to add not all queries you see in slow query log are really running  slow. You need to pay attention that some queries are waiting in the queue to be executed. But, since there are other slow queries are running they appear in the slow query log as queries which passed the long_query_time value and you think they are running slow.

After you let your server to run for a while and collect some slow queries, you need to use slowquerydump [more info click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldumpslow.html) and that will generate a nice formatted file for you so, you could find the queries, how many times been ran, table lock-time,... and run them one by one to see if they are really running slow or stayed too long in the queue to be executed.

Let me know if you have any quetion.